# Extract data from Windows 8 Store app localstorage

Tags: javascript, windows-8

I need to retrieve some data from a running windows 8 store app's html5 localstorage. Is it possible to inspect the localstorage of a running/installed Windows 8 store JavaScript application?

I cannot seem to find where the localstorage file is located.

My guess at first was that it was in an ldf or mdf file in the appdata folder somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, all Windows Store apps data located at "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\". There will be a lot of folders with application package names, so find the one you need and check inside.

For example, when I'm saving some json data in LocalStorage, it will be at "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\MyApplicationPackageName\LocalState\mydata.json".

Hope that's what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but if you need check it out/use it in your own application, try this:

```
var localSettings = applicationData.localSettings;
var localFolder = applicationData.localFolder;
```

See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465118.aspx